# Filling in the values of a column based on matching strings from the column of another dataset

Tags: r, dataframe, match, factors

I am working with the following two datasets :

`will_can`

```
structure(list(will_can.REGION = c("AB", "B", "B", "B", "BB", 
"BB", "BD", "BH", "BH", "BH", "BR", "BS", "BS", "BT", "BT", "CF", 
"CF", "CM", "CO", "CV", "CV", "CV", "CW", "DA", "DA", "DD", "DE", 
"DE", "DG", "DG", "DG", "DG", "DL", "DN", "DT", "E", "E", "E", 
"EH", "EH", "EH", "EH", "EH", "EH", "EH", "EX", "EX", "EX", "FK", 
"FK", "FY", "G", "G", "G", "GL", "GL", "HA", "HD", "HD", "IV", 
"KA", "KA", "KA", "KA", "KA", "KA", "KA", "KA", "KA", "KA", "KA", 
"KA", "KA", "KA", "KA", "KA", "KA", "KT", "KY", "KY", "KY", "L", 
"L", "L", "LA", "LA", "LE", "LE", "M", "M", "ME", "ME", "MK", 
"ML", "N", "N", "N", "NE", "NG", "NN", "NN", "NR", "NW", "OL", 
"OX", "OX", "PH", "PO", "PR", "RG", "RH", "RM", "RM", "S", "S", 
"S", "S", "SA", "SE", "SE", "SE", "SE", "SE", "SG", "SL", "SN", 
"SN", "SO", "SO", "SO", "SS", "ST", "ST", "ST", "ST", "SW", "SW", 
"SW", "SW", "SY", "SY", "SY", "TA", "TD", "TD", "TN", "TW", "UB", 
"UB", "W", "W", "W", "W", "WA", "WC", "WD")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-156L))
```

`will_can_region_norm`

```
structure(list(norm = c(67.3112073766083, 0, 62.9924341677094, 
0, 134.940019161483, 86.0271073135687, 233.710968710152, 0, 0, 
136.210220315945, 72.0106074505199, 54.9624828839958, 0, 0, 46.5061888459603, 
0, 51.9149234846709, 85.3970454501009, 0, 0, 141.438961332615, 
122.50716299382, 197.887432921107, 96.646567080111, 108.996678489718, 
873.779493880704, 0, 109.106806944561, 56.7421763178016, 249.99781251914, 
0, 106.993398828272, 0, 182.997053590583, 0, 225.716259764203, 
217.655353412983, 98.8344746903195, 70.3435951664196, 106.870878390986, 
0, 0, 113.255439262354, 226.344150395729, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 92.5698187029358, 0, 1159.88543061088, 59.5746039659052, 
0, 217.977759293264, 88.627745595238, 155.299651064979, 0, 70.3301130229532, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 36.166169734453, 162.12380892704, 74.7710230881704, 
112.29824076945, 120.249189991435, 25.6209421071498, 36.7120335621411, 
115.238964414265, 0, 50.4621322067494, 59.9490876378327, 82.9160720202368, 
132.342362545417, 0, 0, 209.987774511768, 0, 45.0104437732687, 
59.5244437425851, 54.7420581590574, 77.921490980977, 132.545922191567, 
100.083647410414, 51.5757713324224, 102.602449571922, 98.8984492920948, 
0, 129.885834248271, 0, 189.332549749021, 149.846130500895, 0, 
0, 73.4653456617979, 220.103517986062, 111.317004279081, 375.711503660056, 
156.229153172374, 760.35739839154, 0, 83.1515916711375, 0, 0, 
0, 73.5483180088058, 269.518568414391, 102.141462145838, 55.2886923953334, 
151.949727736478, 148.297412239816, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), REGION = c("AB", 
"AL", "B", "BA", "BB", "BD", "BH", "BL", "BN", "BR", "BS", "BT", 
"CA", "CB", "CF", "CH", "CM", "CO", "CR", "CT", "CV", "CW", "DA", 
"DD", "DE", "DG", "DH", "DL", "DN", "DT", "DY", "E", "EC", "EH", 
"EN", "EX", "FK", "FY", "G", "GL", "GU", "GY", "HA", "HD", "HG", 
"HP", "HR", "HS", "HU", "HX", "IG", "IM", "IP", "IV", "JE", "KA", 
"KT", "KW", "KY", "L", "LA", "LD", "LE", "LL", "LN", "LS", "LU", 
"M", "ME", "MK", "ML", "N", "NE", "NG", "NN", "NP", "NR", "NW", 
"OL", "OX", "PA", "PE", "PH", "PL", "PO", "PR", "RG", "RH", "RM", 
"S", "SA", "SE", "SG", "SK", "SL", "SM", "SN", "SO", "SP", "SR", 
"SS", "ST", "SW", "SY", "TA", "TD", "TF", "TN", "TQ", "TR", "TS", 
"TW", "UB", "W", "WA", "WC", "WD", "WF", "WN", "WR", "WS", "WV", 
"YO", "ZE")), row.names = c(NA, -124L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am trying to add a new column, `will_can$norm`, which would contain values of `will_can_region_norm$norm` based on matching values of the variable `"REGION"` which is the same in both datasets. So gaps from the second dataset to the first would be automatically filled based on matching strings of `REGION`

Based on another question in the forum I tried the following function:

`will_can2 <- merge(will_can, will_can_region_norm[,"norm"], by = "REGION", all=TRUE)`

But I get the following error:

Error in fix.by(by.y, y) :
'by' must specify a unique correct column [translated from French]

Is there something I'm missing here? Would be grateful for some help !

Cameron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your `merge(will_can, will_can_region_norm[,"norm"], by = "REGION", all=TRUE)` command to work, both data.frames would need a column called `REGION`. In your example:

- `will_can` doesn't have this column, but it does have one called `will_can.REGION`.
- You've extracted a single column from `will_can_norm` called `norm`, and tried to merge based on that single column. Unfortunately, the `merge()` command never sees the `REGION` column of `will_can_norm`.

In your case, try something like

```
merge(will_can, will_can_region_norm, by.x = "will_can.REGION", by.y="REGION", all=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked and I then just had to remove rows containing ```NA```!

Comment: @Cameron, regarding the `NA` values, have you tried playing with the parameters `all`, `all.x`, `all.y`?

Comment: No I didn't, I added a separate function to remove them : `will_can2 <- will_can2[complete.cases(will_can2), ]`